# Sending a message to a priority queue with bind=true

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I got a problem when sending a message to a `Priority Queue`. If I set `bind` to true, then I 'm getting a `PRECONDITION_FAILED` error because the Send is trying to create the same Queue but without the argument `x-max-priority`.

The complete error:

> PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue
>   'TestQueue' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '1'
>   of type 'signedint'

Can I adjust the Send Endpoint Uri, so it Sends the message to the `Priority Queue` instead of trying to create another queue without the argument `x-max-priority`? Maybe there is a way to pass this argument via the Send Endpoint Uri?

- this SendEndpoint works: `rabbitmq://host:5672/TestQueue?queue=TestQueue`
- this SendEndpoint fails: `rabbitmq://host:5672/TestQueue?queue=TestQueue&bind=true`

We want to keep the `bind=true` argument, because it gives us a guarantee for message delivery.

**Expected behavior**

Expected behavior would be that `Send` should pick the priority queue, because priority is set in the `SendContext`:

```
await sendEndpoint.Send(message, sendContext =>
{
  context.SetPriority(1);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the queue argument in the URI for the send endpoint? For example:

`GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:<name>?x-max-priority=1"))`

Comment: That doesn't work, also tried `priority=1`

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but this is why producers shouldn't define the behavior of the consumers. And why it's important for consumers to define the broker topology, and not the producer. There isn't a way to set the queue max priority from `Send`.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thanks for your message, is there a best practice that only Consumers should define the broker topology or is this more like a Masstransit point of view?

Comment: I would be interested to know if you have found a solution @Ozkan, thanks.

Comment: According to these issues:
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/418
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/482
The use of priority seems to be supported in a send context. So I don't understand why we got this error. Also you're right, with bind=false it works, but what exactly are the consequences ? (cc @ChrisPatterson)

Comment: You just need to make sure the queue is setup and ready, or have alternate plans setup.